# Display Excel 2007 Document in Browser using COM

Tags: c#, com, interop, activex, ms-office

I want to display and edit MS Excel File from client side using ActiveX COM object. The user would be allowed to edit the file and save it to local PC. Then It can be uploaded to remote server.

So, can you give me some example of displaying Word, Excel, Powerpoint etc document in Internet Explorer 8.0 using COM. I could not find such ocx files for that purpose . Can you help me finding it.

Thanks
Maksud

Comment: I wanted something like http://www.officeocx.com/index.htm. I wanted to develop that solution from scratch. I could not find the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I think those controls would violate the MS Office distribution or EULA licensing agreements with Microsoft. Since an ActiveX control that emulates Word, Excel, PowerPoint would potentially give unlimited and anonymous users access to the software without paying for it. There's other Microsoft technologies that allow you to leverage the end-user's MS Offices licenses that allow them to save back to the web server. I think WebDAV used to be used (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781730%28WS.10%29.aspx), I don't know what's out there now, but I'm sure there's a solution.

Comment: But I have to install Microsoft Office first on my desktop, then only I can use the active x control. So, I don't think anyone can not edit until he/she has installed MS Office.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the use of [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com) would solve these issues.  I'm pretty sure there's a way to leverage some sort of mix of Google Docs and the associated APIs to do something akin to what you are trying to do.  I admit this isn't quite a perfect match for your goals.

Comment: I wanted something like google but want to host the files in our server. Also need to store more filetypes.

Comment: @Maksud: Google's API might let you maintain a copy of the files on your own server (by grabbing it from Google once it's edited).  I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a use case that [Office Live Workspace](http://workspace.officelive.com) was created for. It's free, it's collaborative, and it allows you to determine sharing permissions.